# how to use assertion in selenium so that if it throws assertion error next line will not skip(java)

Tags: java, selenium

I am using assert to verify the scenario in Selenium webdriver.
Below is my code. If I get assertion error in my first line, the execution is not happening for next line. But I want to execute the next line as well and want to print the fail report in testng xslt. I am using ANT to trigger my build.

```
Assert.assertEquals(actualdatesent, expecteddatesent, "comparing assert date");
Assert.assertEquals(actualuccnumber, expecteduccnumber);
```

**Edit**

Try-catch block

```
try
{ 
    Assert.assertEquals(actualdatesent, expecteddatesent, "date validation failed"); 
    Assert.assertEquals(actualuccnumber, expecteduccnumber, number validation failed);
} 
catch(Throwable T)
{
    ErrorUtils.addVerificationFailure(T); 
    SeleniumScreenshot.takeFailedScreenshot(testname);
}
```

Comment: Use testNG's `SoftAssert` as below. `private static SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();` `softAssert.assertEquals(actualuccnumber, expecteduccnumber);`

Comment: Thanks for your input.
it's working , i am able to proceed with next line as well.
But i want to add the failed message to my Testng report.
can you please let me know how can i add the failed message to my report.
below is my catch block code
try{
Assert.assertEquals(actualdatesent, expecteddatesent,"date validation failed");
Assert.assertEquals(actualuccnumber, expecteduccnumber,number validation failed);  
}

Comment: catch(Throwable T){
   ErrorUtils.addVerificationFailure(T); 
   SeleniumScreenshot.takeFailedScreenshot(testname);
  }
normally when i use simple Assert ,when it throws assertion error catch block will take this to add verification failure () and it is being displayed in my report.
But in soft assert case how i should implement this.should i call the Add verification failure() directly by putting if else condition while using soft assert.

Comment: Adding your comment as edit in code. If you want to send message along with assertion use `softAssert.assertEquals(actualuccnumber, expecteduccnumber,String message);` Although I have not used the message method. But check where it is displaying that .

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to surround every assert with `try {} catch (AssertionError ex)` and store the messages from exception in a list. At the end of method you will need to check if list is not empty and throw `AssertionError` yourself with all messages from list concatenated.